# Oracle - Convert UTC Date to Local Date Time US Format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have datetime in the UTC timezone and would like to convert it to the US datetime format MM/DD/YYYY and adjust to the local time zone.

Got it converted in a few steps via a script ...

Do you think is possible to do it using a SELECT statement? Not sure if we can know the timezone configured on the server. Would be glad to get some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of your column?

Comment: You say "US datetime format" - which time zone? There are more than just one in the US.

Comment: You referred to 'local time zone' but then also the time zone of the server; so what do you mean by 'local' - the server/database time zone (to match systimestamp) or the user's session time zone (to match `current_timestamp`), or a specific fixed time zone?

Comment: Column data type - Timestamp convert to DateTime. Possible ?
Timezone = I am not sure but follow Chicago. Source is UTC
I am trying to find if I can know the timezone from Database configuration or settings but if not, I just hard code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Here is a step-by-step of the process

 I will start with a timestamp in UTC

    SQL> select timestamp '2021-07-01 09:00:00 +00:00' ts from dual;
    
    TS
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    01-JUL-21 09.00.00.000000000 AM +00:00

Assuming this is stored in some sort of table, the first thing we can do is convert it to the desired time zone. In my case, I live in Perth, Australia so I do:

    SQL> with my_table as (
      2  select timestamp '2021-07-01 09:00:00 +00:00' ts from dual
      3  )
      4  select ts at time zone 'Australia/Perth' as perth_time
      5  from my_table;
    
    PERTH_TIME
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    01-JUL-21 05.00.00.000000000 PM AUSTRALIA/PERTH

9am UTC is 5pm in Perth (we're 8 hours in front).  Now I want that output in a format that I want, so I can TO_CHAR that in the normal way

SQL> with my_table as (
  2  select timestamp '2021-07-01 09:00:00 +00:00' ts from dual
  3  )
  4  select to_char(ts at time zone 'Australia/Perth','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as perth_time
  5  from my_table;

PERTH_TIME
-------------------
07/01/2021 17:00:00
```

and we're done

Comment: Thanks... tested it works well. Now, I need to see how I save it correctly into the table and then convert to date/time string.

Comment: select zdatetime, zdatetime at time zone 'Australia/Perth' as Perth_Time FROM myTable